# Legacy code & Dependency Injection - Is there any compromise in having both communicating?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, legacy-code

I'm handling a project composed by a big mount of legacy code. With legacy I mean mainly a big class library that contains all the business logic of the application. This business logic is composed by interconnected classes. With interconnected I mean that instances of classes are created (`new`) directly inside other classes.

A newer part of this application uses dependency injection in different class libraries. Unfortunately those class libraries needed to access legacy code, so:

- there is a dependency between those new class libraries and the old legacy one
- some instances of legacy classes are created (`new`) inside the new one

Everything cohesists perfectly, since there are no points where old code need to access the new one. Until now. Let me explain:

- old code has classes that do some kinds of computations
- new code has classes that do other kinds of computations

I now need to sum these computations together, inside a old legacy class.

Obviously there is no problem in doing that by accessing old computation classes. The problem arises when I need to get the new computation classes as I cannot instantiate them directly (because they need some different parameters, injected by the DI container). In order to let everything work, I would need to let the DI container inject those new classes inside the constructor of the old legacy code, but I guess you all get the point: everything comes down to a point where almost the whole code base would need to be rewritten, because it's full of dependencies.

I know this is quite normal with DI, but I'm trying to figure how if there is any (dirty) way to do this or if simply this is not feasible.

As DI container I'm using Ninject and I also tried the Property Injection but it's not working. I guess because the Property is injected if the class containing that property is instantiated by the DI container.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could reformat the question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem. The current explanation, leaves too much open for interpretation. A minimal code example would help.

Comment: are you able to modify the legacy codebase?